# Too many constructors with 1 parameters. The behaviour is unpredictable

Tags: wpf, resharper

Out of seemingly nowhere, ReSharper started reporting this warning in all my `.xaml` files:

`Too many constructors with 1 parameters. The behaviour is unpredictable`

[image]

It seems that every use of `{x:Type}` in my project is now causing this warning. I've tried the following things to clear the warning--all to no avail:

- Removing a recently-added NuGet package
- Clearing my ReSharper cache
- Clean/Rebuild solution

I should note that my project builds and runs just fine. I am stumped. What's going on here?

Comment: I discovered why this is happening, but not how to fix it. In order to use the `MvvmValidation` NuGet package, I had to add a reference to `System.Windows`. The `System.Windows` reference causes these warnings to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like ReSharper simply doesn't like `System.Windows` being referenced in a WPF application. I reverted my reference to `MvvmValidation` to the `net40-client` version and copied the classes I needed that were only available in the portable version (the version that was requiring the `System.Windows` reference).